# which one will call first either constructor or action method in vf page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

In Visual force Page Either Action Method will fire first or Controller constructor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its outlined pretty well on the [DOCS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_get_request.htm)

The constructor executes first

> 1. The constructor methods on the associated custom controller or controller extension classes are called, instantiating the controller
>      objects.
> 2. ......
> 3. The page then executes any assignTo attributes on any custom components on the page. After the assignTo methods are executed,
>      expressions are evaluated, **the action attribute on the 
>      component is evaluated**, and all other method calls, such as getting
>      or setting a property value, are made.

Answer (score 0):

Your controller's constructor will call first and then your apex:page action will call.